# Постоянный посыл сообщения WM_MOUSEMOVE

Tags: c++, winapi

Приветствую. Есть задача: при движении мыши в окне должен двигаться статик внутри данного окна. По неизвестной мне причине сообщение WM_MOUSEMOVE отрабатывает постоянно если курсор мыши находится в окне, но при этом не двигается. Сам статик, как и диалоговое окно, созданы в ресурсах проекта. Проверялось на 2-х ноутбуках где программно отключался тачпад и отсоединялась мышь.
Сам код:

```
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void GetStaticRect(HWND hWnd, RECT &rect);

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG), NULL, DlgProc);
}

HWND hStatic;
RECT rect;

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
        return TRUE;

    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        hStatic = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_RUNNINGSTATIC);
        return TRUE;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:    
        GetStaticRect(hWnd, rect);
        MoveWindow(hStatic, rect.left + 1, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, TRUE);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

void GetStaticRect(HWND hWnd, RECT &rect)
{
    GetWindowRect(hStatic, &rect);

    POINT p;

    p.x = rect.left;
    p.y = rect.top;
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
    rect.left = p.x;
    rect.top = p.y;

    p.x = rect.right;
    p.y = rect.bottom;
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
    rect.right = p.x;
    rect.bottom = p.y;
}
```

Прошу помочь с нахождением ошибки. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: у вас switch не закрыт в примере.А вообще MSDN говорит что если приложение обрабатывает это сообщение то оно должно вернуть 0, т.е. FALSE

Comment: Ошибся при копировании кода. В оригинале там присутствует скобка перед "return FALSE". Поправил пример.

Comment: Попробуйте переделать WinMain как в примере здесь http://www.softcraft.ru/coding/winapi/windlg/

Comment: В чем проблема-то, не пойму?